# Where to see the stored data in derby database in j2me

Tags: java, netbeans, java-me, derby

I created MIDlet class which contains name and number and i used RecordStore to store the data in apache derby database.The program is executing successfully.Now i want to see my entered data in derby database.Please help me where i can see.I am using netbeans IDE.

Answer (score 1):

The database data is stored in files in the filesystem. The exact location of those files is controlled by the JDBC connection URL that you specified when you opened the database. Generally this URL describes a filesystem path. If the path is an absolute path, look there. If it is a relative path, look for the location relative to the current directory where your program was running.

Here's more information: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/devguide/cdevdvlp40724.html

Answer (score 1):

In netbeans: services -databases-connect your database-display data find you user display-Right click on the table and view data.