# Does Embedded Derby Jar actually create a database

Tags: jpa, derby

I followed some of the steps in this tutorial http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaPersistenceAPI/article.html#lombok to add a JPA Context tomy Dynamic Web Project. I am able to add data and retrieve it successfully. But is it possible if I wanted to check it in like an actual database? If so, where can I find it. I'm doing this on a mac and the path to my persistence.jdbc.url is something like /user/vny/database/simplDb. Also, is this a good way to implement JPA or is it better to install a database first and then make the connection.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/a/15250321/193453

Answer (score 0):

> If you are using Apache derby database then it will create a static
>   database for you in which you can insert data and also retrieve the
>   data from that but as its a static database it will vanish as soon as
>   you turn off your application.So the data from derby never get stored
>   anywhere rather than static block of memory.

Comment: Is it better to install a db and then make a JPA connection or is this fine?

Comment: Note, the above answer is only true if you create an in memory database like the following: jdbc:derby:memory:myDB;create=true

Without "memory" in there, it will create an actual file storing the database. See the answer Bryan Pendleton linked to above for more information